# Storyboards references

Tags: uiviewcontroller, storyboard, uistoryboardsegue

I am building an app which will use 103 view controllers all with pictures some with movies, all with go-back and main buttons. There will be 17 subjects that I can use references doing this I can split my working area to be easier to work, it will probably be heavy because of the pictures and eleven movies inside. My question: Is there any other way to deal with this large amount of view controllers and storyboards?

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't need a new type of view controller to display different data; you need a new type when the style of presentation and interaction is different.  (IOW, are you *sure* about the 103?)

Comment: Hi Phillip, the complete set of pictures are 103, there will be small variations in most of the picture, for example, the main photo of a subject is a car panel and the next will be the same panel with speed of 30miles/hours next will be with 45m/h, next RPM 3000 and so on. Do you know any other way to do that other than 103 pictures?

Comment: So far you've only described a need for one view controller and a way to change which picture it displays.

Comment: Is it possible to have only one view controller with different buttons to each picture?

Comment: Sure...or a couple of buttons to move forward and back if 100+ buttons seems a bit much.  (Or a slider, or a page control, or....)

Comment: @Phillip Mills, slider or page control will not work, the idea is the user click in some parts do the panel and find the explanation about this instrument or knob. I cannot think other than view controllers and buttons with segues to have this feature. I am really concern about all the pictures and how heavy will be :(